# Error loading image from class path in java

Tags: java, image, email, classpath, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an image via java mail api using the following code;

```
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            message.setSubject(username +"'s Second Story Forgotten Password");
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EmailAddress.ADMIN.getValue()));
            message.setContent(msg, "text/html");
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));


             Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();


             BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
             htmlPart.setContent(msg, "text/html");
             multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

             BodyPart imgPart = new MimeBodyPart();
             DataSource ds = getImage();
             imgPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
             imgPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "the-img-1");
             multipart.addBodyPart(imgPart);
             message.setContent(multipart);
             transport.connect();
             transport.sendMessage(message,message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
```

The ds = getImage can be seen below

```
private static DataSource getImage(){
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    if (classLoader == null) {
        classLoader = MailSender.class.getClassLoader();
    }
    DataSource ds = new FileDataSource("/VimbaEmailLogo.png");
    return ds;
}
```

I have a resources folder with my image inside that has been added to the class path. I know this is done correctly as I am able to load other files from here.

Every time I try to load a png and send the email i get the following error

```
DEBUG SMTP: IOException while sending, closing, THROW: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /VimbaEmailLogo.png (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:97)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:305)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1608)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:961)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:553)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:103)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:889)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1608)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1849)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1196)
    at com.secondstory.mailsender.MailSender.sendSimpleMessage(MailSender.java:75)
    at com.secondstory.mailsender.MailSender.generateLostPasswordEmail(MailSender.java:124)
    at com.secondstory.mailsender.MailSender.main(MailSender.java:149)
```

Am I loading the image correctly for sending an email - if not how do I need to change it? Thanks

Comment: Here is your answer - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /VimbaEmailLogo.png (No such file or directory). Try change VIMBA_LOGO  value.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a class loader, but then try to load the image from the file system using a [`FileDataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/FileDataSource.html) object. Change it to a [`URLDataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/URLDataSource.html) and load the image from the URL that you obtain from the class loader.

```
private static DataSource getImage() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    if (classLoader == null) {
        classLoader = MailSender.class.getClassLoader();
    }
    DataSource ds = new URLDataSource(classLoader.getResource("VimbaEmailLogo.png"));
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: this approach results in a datasource being populated with no url inside of it (the url is null) therefore i assume it isn't picking up the file from the resources folder?

Comment: Might need to drop the slash.

Comment: You mentioned in your question that you're able to load other resources from your resource folder through the class loader correctly, right?

Comment: yes that is correct, i am able to load a p12 file and properties file - to do this i use the following approach (properties file)`try(InputStream resourceStream = DatabaseUtilities.class.getResourceAsStream(appName.getValue())) {
   if(resourceStream != null){`